# The Lebesgue measure of zero set of a polynomial function is zero

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, lebesgue-measure, analyticity, analytic-functions

> Suppose $f :\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a non zero polynomial(more generally smooth) function.Suppose $Z(f)=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x)=0 \}$. Show that  Lebesgue measure of $Z(f)$ is zero.

I am trying to use induction on $n$.The result holds obviously if $n=1$.Could someone give me some idea to prove the inductive step.The proof without induction on $n$ is also appreciated.

Comment: It does not hold for a smooth function. Analytic, on the other hand...

Comment: Thanks i dint know that.Is there any simple counter example?

Comment: $$f(x)=\cases{0&if $x\leq0$\\e^{-1/x^2}&if $x>0$}$$

Comment: @Arthur: Ah "the" famous counterexample.Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need an inductive step? Is it ok if I suggest an alternate proof?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sure,i am interested in other proofs also as i have mentioned in the question

Comment: @AlexM.: Analytic functions are continuous, and full-measure sets are dense.  So if a continuous function vanishes almost everywhere, it vanishes everywhere.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose the theorem is established for polynomials in $n-1$ variables.  Let $p$ be a nontrivial polynomial in $n$ variables, say of degree $k \ge 1$ in $x_n$.  We can then write
$$p(\mathbf{x}, x_n) = \sum_{j=0}^k p_j(\mathbf{x}) x_n^j$$
where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})$ and $p_0, \dots, p_k$ are polynomials in $n-1$ variables, where at least $p_k$ is nontrivial.

Let us note that since $p$ is continuous, the zero set $Z(p)$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now if $(\mathbf{x}, x_n)$ is such that $p(\mathbf{x}, x_n) = 0$ then there are two possibilities:

1. $p_0(\mathbf{x}) = \dots = p_k(\mathbf{x}) = 0$, or
2. $x_n$ is a root of the (nontrivial) one-variable polynomial $p_{\mathbf{x}}(t) =\sum_{j=0}^k p_j(\mathbf{x}) t^j$.

Let $A,B$ be the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where these respective conditions hold, so that $Z(p) = A \cup B$.

Use the inductive hypothesis to show $A$ has measure zero.

Use the fundamental theorem of algebra (its easy direction) to show that for each fixed $\mathbf{x}$, there are finitely many $t$ such that $(\mathbf{x},t) \in B$.  (Indeed, there are at most $k$.) A finite set has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}$.  Now apply Fubini's theorem to conclude that $B$ has measure zero.  (Note that $B = Z(p) \setminus A$ is measurable.)

Comment: Technically, you're not using the fundamental theorem of algebra in the last paragraph, are you? A degree-$n$ polynomial having no more than $n$ roots only rests on the assertion that $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ are fields.

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel: True, I tend to think of FTA as "a degree $n$ polynomial has exactly $n$ complex roots", but you're right that we're using the easy direction here - the hard part is "at least one root".

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned in a comment above, the result doesn't hold for a general smooth function. Suppose $f(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is a polynomial, and assume without loss of generality that all $\partial f/\partial X_i\not\equiv 0$. By the constant rank theorem, the result holds off the $Z(\partial f/\partial X_i)$. Now induct on the degree of $f$.