# Sards theorem for polynomial

Tags: differential-topology

I'm having some struggles with an aspect about something apparently trivial about Sard's theorem, but couldn't find anything online.

Let $f$ be a polynomial.

According to Sard's theorem, the image $f(Z)$ of the set of critical values 
$$Z = \{a \in X : f'(a) = 0\}$$
has measure zero.

What if I want to show that the set $Z$ itself has measure zero in the domain of $f$?

I feel like it's so simple but i just can't get behind it.

Comment: The set of zeroes of a non-zero polynomial always has measure $0$. Apply that to $f'$.

Comment: What measure is there on $X$? Are we in the context where $X\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\mu(A)$ is just the Lebesgue measure of $A$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @Gae.S. Good point -- since the OP refers to Sard's theorem, we should probably assume that $X$ is a manifold. In this case, "measure zero" is unambiguous without defining a measure on $X$, and may be different than "has Lebesgue measure zero with respect to some embedding $X \to \mathbb{R}^n$". I think the result should hold as long as $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is nonconstant and is induced by the composition of a proper embedding $X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a polynomial $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, although I could easily be wrong; I don't see immediately how to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

In this case Sard's theorem is not needed. If $p$ is a nonzero polynomial, its set of zeros is finite by induction on its degree. If $f$ is not constant, then the set $Z$ of critical *points* is therefore also finite (it is the set of zeros of the polynomial $f'$), so it has measure zero!

Edit: @Captain Lama has suggested that you may be dealing with a polynomial in more than one variable. In this case, we cannot deduce that the set of zeros of $f'$ is finite, but we can still show that it has measure zero. You can do this with Fubini's theorem and induction on the number of variables – see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920527/19006) for an algebraic proof. You do need to make sure that $f$ is not constant, of course!

Comment: I would assume that $f$ can be a polynomial in several variables, so the set of zeroes of $f'$ needs not be finite. Unless the OP says they had only one variable in mind.

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked that possibility